# switching background image using array

Tags: arraylist, background-image, setinterval

im trying to change the bacground-image attribute using an array and a time interval, this in the code i have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bgArray =[
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/01.png",
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/02.png",
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/03.png",
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/04.png",
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/05.png",
    "IMG/Trusti/phones/06.png"
];
var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $("#telefoondiv").animate({'background-image' : 'bgArray[i]'});
        i++;
    }100);
});
```

hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

use css function to set styles instead of animate.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var bgArray =[
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRHN0Fxrd_RQqqwpnngUjjkah_tap84fzu6ltuH1lAZs3yGT2QH",
        "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUgm_VIAjymgGEkYLhQVSQajHCr4qGAC2yqnzu7YbKAefn-iYJ-w",
        "http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg"
    ];
    var i = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#telefoondiv").css({'background-image' : "url(" + bgArray[i] + ")"});
            i++;
          
          if(i == bgArray.length){
              i = 0;
           }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="telefoondiv" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```